# AWS CDK - Best practice on where to store the account id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am just playing around with AWS CDK and am a bit confused about where to actually store the a*ws account id* which is necessary to make it all work.

In the official [AWS CDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html) itself, it's stated that you should put the whole environment - and with it the *account id* - into the code itself (at least for production environments).

However, as I am checking that code into git aswell, this means the *account id* would be under version control.

I always considered the *account id* a somewhat sensitive information. It just doesn't feel right to check that in - also because I might want to open source what I am working on.

Usually I'd go ahead and just put it into an environment variable that I provide at runtime - but  the documentation actively discourages doing exactly that, and this is where my confusion is coming from.

I know this might be a somewhat opinionated question, but: 
**Is this really the best practice to do right now? Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's another option you can use. It's `SSM - Parameter Store`.

The best practice is to store those secrets to Parameter Store manually then use them on the CDK by name.

For example:

a) Go to SSM(Systems Manager) and click the Parameter Store to add a new key-value set. (key: ssm_account_id, value: xxxxx)

```js
ecs.Secret.fromSsmParameter(ssm.StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(
this, 'account_id', 'ssm_account_id')),
```

Then you don't have to expose your creds on the version control system.

SSM - Parameter Store:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html

Comment: Sorry for my VERY late response to this - I acutally did not pursue this further. But: Wouldn't I need my Account Id to access the Parameter Store as well?

Comment: @DavidLosert Nomorally you don't need the ID to access any kind of resources, the way AWS authorizes CDK is by your credential, which could be IAM Role or User base. For example, if you are going to deploy CDK on your local machine, then your permissions would come from ~/.aws/credientials .

Comment: So I came around to trying this out today - however, unfortunately it doesn't work. AWS CDK really expects that account_id within the `env` Section of a `cdk.Stack` before doing even one call to AWS itself. So as it seems at least for this env, one can not use the SSM, at least not within the template itself. I therefore fell back on using my own ENV-Variable which is now also the documented way to go I think. Thanks anyways for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy stacks that are not environment-agnostic (that is, you need to provide the `env` prop), you can use the `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variables - they are populated by the CDK CLI and the values correspond to the credentials you are using to execute `cdk` commands.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to store the account ID anywhere, you could get the account ID from the stack itself. In my use case I name my s3 bucket by appending the account ID

```
    const s3Bucket = new Bucket(this, 'S3Bucket',{
      bucketName: `bucket-name-${cdk.Stack.of(this).account}`,
    });
```